# Would span tags on each letter, syllable or word, on thousands of words slow a site?

Tags: html

A site has a very long text, say thousands of words, and each word, or letter or syllable is enclosed in a span tag.

Will this slow the site noticeably, is there any possible negative effect of such an amount of tags ?

Would this change if the tags have id's or classes?

The case-scenario is some sort of karaoke-like text highlighting, on a long text.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if it would be noticeable, but would think it'd definitely slow down the rendering a bit. Would try and see how much.

Answer (score -1):

Not so you would notice.

Here I even do it after the fact so it loads quicker

https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/n3bgjukr/

Using script:

```
document.querySelectorAll("p")
  .forEach(p => p.innerHTML = p
    .textContent
    .trim()
    .split(' ')
    .map(word => `<span>${word}</span>`)
    .join(" "));
```

Result

```css
span {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div id="Inner">



  <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
  <h4>"Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..."</h4>
  <h5>"There is no one who loves pain itself, who seeks after it and wants to have it, simply because it is pain..."</h5>


  <hr>

  <div id="Content">
    <div class="boxed">

      <div id="lipsum">
        <p><span>Lorem</span> <span>ipsum</span> <span>dolor</span> <span>sit</span> <span>amet,</span> <span>consectetur</span> <span>adipiscing</span> <span>elit.</span> <span>Praesent</span> <span>eros</span> <span>purus,</span> <span>accumsan</span>          <span>nec</span> <span>convallis</span> <span>a,</span> <span>maximus</span> <span>vitae</span> <span>justo.</span> <span>Integer</span> <span>volutpat</span> <span>nibh</span> <span>eu</span> <span>nulla</span> <span>dictum,</span> <span>at</span>          <span>consectetur</span> <span>lorem</span> <span>blandit.</span> <span>Pellentesque</span> <span>at</span> <span>ligula</span> <span>sit</span> <span>amet</span> <span>ante</span> <span>varius</span> <span>efficitur</span> <span>eu</span> <span>et</span>          <span>sem.</span> <span>Praesent</span> <span>in</span> <span>dui</span> <span>nec</span> <span>nunc</span> <span>tempor</span> <span>vehicula.</span> <span>Morbi</span> <span>quis</span> <span>semper</span> <span>dui.</span> <span>Phasellus</span>          <span>suscipit</span> <span>purus</span> <span>nec</span> <span>nunc</span> <span>mattis,</span> <span>vitae</span> <span>placerat</span> <span>mauris</span> <span>fermentum.</span> <span>Proin</span> <span>et</span> <span>ante</span> <span>mattis,</span>          <span>tempor</span> <span>turpis</span> <span>at,</span> <span>semper</span> <span>augue.</span> <span>Suspendisse</span> <span>placerat,</span> <span>tellus</span> <span>vitae</span> <span>iaculis</span> <span>viverra,</span> <span>enim</span>          <span>sem</span> <span>tincidunt</span> <span>nunc,</span> <span>a</span> <span>tristique</span> <span>ex</span> <span>dui</span> <span>ac</span> <span>lectus.</span></p>
        <p><span>In</span> <span>hac</span> <span>habitasse</span> <span>platea</span> <span>dictumst.</span> <span>Cras</span> <span>dignissim</span> <span>enim</span> <span>ut</span> <span>fringilla</span> <span>dapibus.</span> <span>Donec</span> <span>posuere</span>          <span>elementum</span> <span>enim,</span> <span>vitae</span> <span>tincidunt</span> <span>orci</span> <span>sagittis</span> <span>et.</span> <span>Integer</span> <span>sagittis</span> <span>egestas</span> <span>sagittis.</span> <span>Donec</span>          <span>a</span> <span>nisi</span> <span>enim.</span> <span>Aenean</span> <span>tempus</span> <span>non</span> <span>lacus</span> <span>at</span> <span>varius.</span> <span>Maecenas</span> <span>vel</span> <span>magna</span> <span>eu</span> <span>lorem</span>          <span>blandit</span> <span>dictum.</span> <span>Class</span> <span>aptent</span> <span>taciti</span> <span>sociosqu</span> <span>ad</span> <span>litora</span> <span>torquent</span> <span>per</span> <span>conubia</span> <span>nostra,</span> <span>per</span>          <span>inceptos</span> <span>himenaeos.</span> <span>Nunc</span> <span>tincidunt</span> <span>orci</span> <span>ac</span> <span>tortor</span> <span>porta,</span> <span>id</span> <span>molestie</span> <span>justo</span> <span>blandit.</span></p>
        <p><span>Nunc</span> <span>sit</span> <span>amet</span> <span>interdum</span> <span>nisl,</span> <span>a</span> <span>porttitor</span> <span>sem.</span> <span>Etiam</span> <span>posuere</span> <span>mollis</span> <span>nisi,</span> <span>non</span>          <span>cursus</span> <span>lectus</span> <span>maximus</span> <span>in.</span> <span>Aliquam</span> <span>in</span> <span>tempor</span> <span>odio.</span> <span>Curabitur</span> <span>neque</span> <span>justo,</span> <span>hendrerit</span> <span>et</span>          <span>iaculis</span> <span>et,</span> <span>ultrices</span> <span>id</span> <span>mi.</span> <span>Curabitur</span> <span>eu</span> <span>lacinia</span> <span>orci.</span> <span>Nullam</span> <span>dui</span> <span>magna,</span> <span>faucibus</span>          <span>id</span> <span>augue</span> <span>at,</span> <span>molestie</span> <span>vehicula</span> <span>nulla.</span> <span>Nullam</span> <span>ultricies</span> <span>ipsum</span> <span>quis</span> <span>sapien</span> <span>viverra,</span> <span>et</span>          <span>suscipit</span> <span>erat</span> <span>pretium.</span> <span>Nam</span> <span>sollicitudin</span> <span>diam</span> <span>facilisis,</span> <span>dapibus</span> <span>neque</span> <span>a,</span> <span>iaculis</span> <span>libero.</span></p>
        <p><span>Quisque</span> <span>sed</span> <span>dolor</span> <span>sit</span> <span>amet</span> <span>felis</span> <span>finibus</span> <span>tempor.</span> <span>In</span> <span>a</span> <span>ornare</span> <span>felis.</span> <span>Donec</span>          <span>at</span> <span>augue</span> <span>at</span> <span>magna</span> <span>pulvinar</span> <span>tincidunt.</span> <span>Fusce</span> <span>non</span> <span>odio</span> <span>tempus,</span> <span>porttitor</span> <span>felis</span> <span>vitae,</span>          <span>feugiat</span> <span>quam.</span> <span>Duis</span> <span>lacus</span> <span>leo,</span> <span>elementum</span> <span>aliquam</span> <span>elementum</span> <span>ut,</span> <span>suscipit</span> <span>ac</span> <span>mi.</span> <span>Maecenas</span>          <span>augue</span> <span>nulla,</span> <span>laoreet</span> <span>sed</span> <span>porta</span> <span>vel,</span> <span>efficitur</span> <span>et</span> <span>neque.</span> <span>Praesent</span> <span>placerat</span> <span>tincidunt</span> <span>ex,</span>          <span>non</span> <span>convallis</span> <span>neque</span> <span>pulvinar</span> <span>nec.</span> <span>Nulla</span> <span>commodo</span> <span>vel</span> <span>urna</span> <span>vitae</span> <span>vestibulum.</span> <span>Fusce</span> <span>euismod</span>          <span>ex</span> <span>ut</span> <span>ex</span> <span>ultrices</span> <span>tempor.</span> <span>Pellentesque</span> <span>vulputate</span> <span>fringilla</span> <span>metus.</span> <span>Suspendisse</span> <span>sagittis</span> <span>cursus</span>          <span>mi,</span> <span>rhoncus</span> <span>feugiat</span> <span>urna</span> <span>convallis</span> <span>et.</span></p>
        <p><span>Nullam</span> <span>auctor</span> <span>condimentum</span> <span>quam,</span> <span>at</span> <span>ultrices</span> <span>magna</span> <span>placerat</span> <span>ultrices.</span> <span>Etiam</span> <span>rhoncus</span> <span>mauris</span>          <span>vitae</span> <span>felis</span> <span>suscipit</span> <span>venenatis.</span> <span>Vivamus</span> <span>ac</span> <span>feugiat</span> <span>ex,</span> <span>et</span> <span>faucibus</span> <span>mi.</span> <span>Ut</span> <span>sollicitudin</span>          <span>justo</span> <span>dolor,</span> <span>vitae</span> <span>euismod</span> <span>odio</span> <span>lobortis</span> <span>vitae.</span> <span>Praesent</span> <span>sed</span> <span>accumsan</span> <span>nibh.</span> <span>Pellentesque</span>          <span>lobortis</span> <span>felis</span> <span>elit,</span> <span>ut</span> <span>auctor</span> <span>odio</span> <span>mollis</span> <span>ac.</span> <span>In</span> <span>et</span> <span>vehicula</span> <span>ipsum.</span> <span>Maecenas</span>          <span>ac</span> <span>venenatis</span> <span>lorem,</span> <span>auctor</span> <span>pellentesque</span> <span>nulla.</span> <span>Ut</span> <span>volutpat</span> <span>nisi</span> <span>imperdiet</span> <span>felis</span> <span>tristique,</span>          <span>eu</span> <span>semper</span> <span>tellus</span> <span>posuere.</span> <span>Nam</span> <span>efficitur</span> <span>condimentum</span> <span>tellus</span> <span>vel</span> <span>bibendum.</span> <span>Interdum</span> <span>et</span>          <span>malesuada</span> <span>fames</span> <span>ac</span> <span>ante</span> <span>ipsum</span> <span>primis</span> <span>in</span> <span>faucibus.</span> <span>Suspendisse</span> <span>venenatis</span> <span>vestibulum</span> <span>elit,</span>          <span>vel</span> <span>volutpat</span> <span>nunc</span> <span>ultrices</span> <span>sit</span> <span>amet.</span></p>
        <p><span>Duis</span> <span>feugiat,</span> <span>justo</span> <span>eu</span> <span>molestie</span> <span>scelerisque,</span> <span>risus</span> <span>ipsum</span> <span>elementum</span> <span>nulla,</span> <span>vitae</span> <span>posuere</span>          <span>sem</span> <span>elit</span> <span>non</span> <span>sem.</span> <span>Curabitur</span> <span>elementum</span> <span>massa</span> <span>non</span> <span>lectus</span> <span>ullamcorper,</span> <span>id</span> <span>pharetra</span> <span>sem</span>          <span>ultricies.</span> <span>Nulla</span> <span>sodales</span> <span>ex</span> <span>felis,</span> <span>nec</span> <span>consequat</span> <span>elit</span> <span>ultrices</span> <span>et.</span> <span>Curabitur</span> <span>fringilla</span>          <span>eleifend</span> <span>sollicitudin.</span> <span>Sed</span> <span>porta</span> <span>neque</span> <span>nec</span> <span>lacus</span> <span>volutpat,</span> <span>vehicula</span> <span>ultricies</span> <span>augue</span> <span>pellentesque.</span>          <span>Fusce</span> <span>hendrerit</span> <span>euismod</span> <span>erat,</span> <span>at</span> <span>bibendum</span> <span>metus</span> <span>lobortis</span> <span>id.</span> <span>Ut</span> <span>dapibus</span> <span>consectetur</span> <span>orci</span>          <span>semper</span> <span>eleifend.</span> <span>Donec</span> <span>placerat</span> <span>accumsan</span> <span>urna,</span> <span>ac</span> <span>malesuada</span> <span>felis</span> <span>varius</span> <span>non.</span> <span>Cras</span> <span>molestie</span>          <span>cursus</span> <span>lorem</span> <span>ut</span> <span>facilisis.</span> <span>Aenean</span> <span>a</span> <span>felis</span> <span>felis.</span> <span>Ut</span> <span>gravida</span> <span>lacinia</span> <span>congue.</span> <span>Curabitur</span>          <span>eget</span> <span>facilisis</span> <span>quam.</span> <span>Curabitur</span> <span>at</span> <span>ex</span> <span>non</span> <span>justo</span> <span>lobortis</span> <span>condimentum.</span> <span>Nunc</span> <span>accumsan</span> <span>rutrum</span>          <span>feugiat.</span> <span>Morbi</span> <span>vitae</span> <span>erat</span> <span>a</span> <span>mi</span> <span>viverra</span> <span>pellentesque</span> <span>nec</span> <span>vitae</span> <span>mauris.</span> <span>Nullam</span> <span>in</span>          <span>eleifend</span> <span>justo.</span></p>
        <p><span>In</span> <span>hac</span> <span>habitasse</span> <span>platea</span> <span>dictumst.</span> <span>Duis</span> <span>orci</span> <span>elit,</span> <span>faucibus</span> <span>ut</span> <span>nunc</span> <span>non,</span> <span>consectetur</span>          <span>interdum</span> <span>dui.</span> <span>Aenean</span> <span>quis</span> <span>massa</span> <span>erat.</span> <span>Orci</span> <span>varius</span> <span>natoque</span> <span>penatibus</span> <span>et</span> <span>magnis</span> <span>dis</span>          <span>parturient</span> <span>montes,</span> <span>nascetur</span> <span>ridiculus</span> <span>mus.</span> <span>Suspendisse</span> <span>porttitor,</span> <span>ante</span> <span>non</span> <span>varius</span> <span>rhoncus,</span> <span>neque</span>          <span>ante</span> <span>tincidunt</span> <span>ligula,</span> <span>sed</span> <span>pretium</span> <span>nisl</span> <span>turpis</span> <span>a</span> <span>magna.</span> <span>Suspendisse</span> <span>non</span> <span>tempor</span> <span>felis,</span>          <span>et</span> <span>rhoncus</span> <span>magna.</span> <span>Ut</span> <span>vehicula</span> <span>odio</span> <span>vel</span> <span>elit</span> <span>sollicitudin</span> <span>porta.</span></p>
        <p><span>Curabitur</span> <span>ac</span> <span>mattis</span> <span>lectus.</span> <span>Aenean</span> <span>viverra</span> <span>porttitor</span> <span>lorem,</span> <span>id</span> <span>laoreet</span> <span>elit</span> <span>elementum</span> <span>nec.</span>          <span>Donec</span> <span>gravida</span> <span>leo</span> <span>non</span> <span>mi</span> <span>auctor,</span> <span>vel</span> <span>tincidunt</span> <span>odio</span> <span>tincidunt.</span> <span>Fusce</span> <span>eu</span> <span>facilisis</span>          <span>diam,</span> <span>non</span> <span>posuere</span> <span>orci.</span> <span>Vestibulum</span> <span>lacinia,</span> <span>nisl</span> <span>eget</span> <span>aliquet</span> <span>consequat,</span> <span>lorem</span> <span>odio</span> <span>pellentesque</span>          <span>quam,</span> <span>id</span> <span>hendrerit</span> <span>ipsum</span> <span>nulla</span> <span>in</span> <span>ipsum.</span> <span>Vestibulum</span> <span>ante</span> <span>ipsum</span> <span>primis</span> <span>in</span> <span>faucibus</span>          <span>orci</span> <span>luctus</span> <span>et</span> <span>ultrices</span> <span>posuere</span> <span>cubilia</span> <span>curae;</span> <span>Nulla</span> <span>a</span> <span>nisi</span> <span>finibus,</span> <span>tempor</span> <span>risus</span>          <span>ut,</span> <span>ultricies</span> <span>lacus.</span> <span>Suspendisse</span> <span>tincidunt</span> <span>varius</span> <span>arcu,</span> <span>eu</span> <span>dapibus</span> <span>enim</span> <span>tincidunt</span> <span>eget.</span>          <span>Sed</span> <span>condimentum</span> <span>massa</span> <span>at</span> <span>purus</span> <span>scelerisque</span> <span>hendrerit.</span></p>
        <p><span>Nunc</span> <span>vel</span> <span>enim</span> <span>congue</span> <span>ex</span> <span>aliquet</span> <span>pulvinar</span> <span>eget</span> <span>vel</span> <span>elit.</span> <span>Nullam</span> <span>finibus</span> <span>fermentum</span>          <span>mollis.</span> <span>Donec</span> <span>fermentum</span> <span>feugiat</span> <span>nisl</span> <span>et</span> <span>hendrerit.</span> <span>Proin</span> <span>suscipit</span> <span>felis</span> <span>orci.</span> <span>Integer</span>          <span>aliquet</span> <span>orci</span> <span>sit</span> <span>amet</span> <span>augue</span> <span>condimentum</span> <span>cursus.</span> <span>Morbi</span> <span>vehicula,</span> <span>nibh</span> <span>sodales</span> <span>gravida</span>          <span>faucibus,</span> <span>leo</span> <span>nulla</span> <span>ullamcorper</span> <span>enim,</span> <span>at</span> <span>lacinia</span> <span>neque</span> <span>nisl</span> <span>finibus</span> <span>tortor.</span> <span>Sed</span> <span>volutpat</span>          <span>odio</span> <span>ut</span> <span>ultrices</span> <span>lobortis.</span> <span>Pellentesque</span> <span>at</span> <span>volutpat</span> <span>justo.</span> <span>Praesent</span> <span>nec</span> <span>metus</span> <span>sit</span> <span>amet</span>          <span>velit</span> <span>aliquet</span> <span>volutpat.</span> <span>Nam</span> <span>tempus</span> <span>luctus</span> <span>justo</span> <span>eu</span> <span>tincidunt.</span> <span>Vivamus</span> <span>commodo</span> <span>enim</span> <span>enim,</span>          <span>vel</span> <span>varius</span> <span>leo</span> <span>interdum</span> <span>sit</span> <span>amet.</span></p>
        <p><span>Pellentesque</span> <span>eu</span> <span>accumsan</span> <span>nunc.</span> <span>Sed</span> <span>ultrices</span> <span>elementum</span> <span>finibus.</span> <span>Aenean</span> <span>non</span> <span>turpis</span> <span>viverra,</span>          <span>faucibus</span> <span>libero</span> <span>vulputate,</span> <span>semper</span> <span>nibh.</span> <span>Maecenas</span> <span>efficitur</span> <span>volutpat</span> <span>lectus</span> <span>facilisis</span> <span>hendrerit.</span> <span>Cras</span>          <span>a</span> <span>dui</span> <span>tincidunt,</span> <span>elementum</span> <span>nisl</span> <span>sit</span> <span>amet,</span> <span>condimentum</span> <span>dui.</span> <span>Donec</span> <span>pulvinar</span> <span>nisi</span> <span>quis</span>          <span>ullamcorper</span> <span>semper.</span> <span>Praesent</span> <span>in</span> <span>ultricies</span> <span>mi,</span> <span>quis</span> <span>lacinia</span> <span>tellus.</span> <span>Morbi</span> <span>rutrum</span> <span>dui</span> <span>sed</span>          <span>mauris</span> <span>tincidunt,</span> <span>et</span> <span>pulvinar</span> <span>libero</span> <span>euismod.</span> <span>Aliquam</span> <span>molestie</span> <span>eu</span> <span>nisi</span> <span>eget</span> <span>elementum.</span>          <span>Vestibulum</span> <span>a</span> <span>malesuada</span> <span>dolor.</span> <span>Nullam</span> <span>vulputate</span> <span>est</span> <span>suscipit</span> <span>nulla</span> <span>sagittis</span> <span>ornare.</span> <span>Aliquam</span>          <span>ac</span> <span>ante</span> <span>in</span> <span>odio</span> <span>consectetur</span> <span>pharetra.</span></p>
        <p><span>Nulla</span> <span>eget</span> <span>ipsum</span> <span>quis</span> <span>velit</span> <span>maximus</span> <span>hendrerit</span> <span>sit</span> <span>amet</span> <span>eu</span> <span>ex.</span> <span>Nullam</span> <span>ultrices</span>          <span>nulla</span> <span>vitae</span> <span>ante</span> <span>pharetra,</span> <span>quis</span> <span>tristique</span> <span>dui</span> <span>gravida.</span> <span>Curabitur</span> <span>quam</span> <span>sem,</span> <span>hendrerit</span>          <span>a</span> <span>ligula</span> <span>in,</span> <span>posuere</span> <span>tincidunt</span> <span>orci.</span> <span>Integer</span> <span>imperdiet</span> <span>convallis</span> <span>hendrerit.</span> <span>Pellentesque</span> <span>porttitor</span>          <span>aliquet</span> <span>lacus</span> <span>vitae</span> <span>commodo.</span> <span>Vestibulum</span> <span>a</span> <span>lacinia</span> <span>risus.</span> <span>Integer</span> <span>at</span> <span>laoreet</span> <span>mi.</span> <span>Morbi</span>          <span>sed</span> <span>ante</span> <span>finibus,</span> <span>sodales</span> <span>tortor</span> <span>sed,</span> <span>consectetur</span> <span>sem.</span> <span>Maecenas</span> <span>turpis</span> <span>massa,</span> <span>sagittis</span>          <span>a</span> <span>nunc</span> <span>nec,</span> <span>feugiat</span> <span>venenatis</span> <span>odio.</span> <span>Ut</span> <span>congue</span> <span>efficitur</span> <span>magna.</span></p>
        <p><span>Maecenas</span> <span>sed</span> <span>ornare</span> <span>sapien.</span> <span>Nullam</span> <span>accumsan</span> <span>dui</span> <span>in</span> <span>tincidunt</span> <span>pulvinar.</span> <span>Aliquam</span> <span>aliquam</span>          <span>ante</span> <span>ex,</span> <span>ut</span> <span>accumsan</span> <span>tellus</span> <span>tempor</span> <span>vitae.</span> <span>Aliquam</span> <span>pharetra,</span> <span>urna</span> <span>pretium</span> <span>facilisis</span> <span>lacinia,</span>          <span>metus</span> <span>risus</span> <span>luctus</span> <span>purus,</span> <span>eget</span> <span>fermentum</span> <span>metus</span> <span>tortor</span> <span>sed</span> <span>turpis.</span> <span>Cras</span> <span>scelerisque</span> <span>rhoncus</span>          <span>dolor,</span> <span>eu</span> <span>faucibus</span> <span>elit</span> <span>vehicula</span> <span>eget.</span> <span>Nunc</span> <span>lobortis</span> <span>ligula</span> <span>leo,</span> <span>et</span> <span>ultricies</span> <span>magna</span>          <span>scelerisque</span> <span>et.</span> <span>Ut</span> <span>mattis</span> <span>dapibus</span> <span>lacus</span> <span>eu</span> <span>maximus.</span> <span>Vestibulum</span> <span>vitae</span> <span>malesuada</span> <span>dui,</span> <span>eget</span>          <span>eleifend</span> <span>lorem.</span> <span>Proin</span> <span>at</span> <span>luctus</span> <span>odio,</span> <span>a</span> <span>faucibus</span> <span>quam.</span> <span>Vivamus</span> <span>felis</span> <span>justo,</span> <span>consequat</span>          <span>non</span> <span>lacinia</span> <span>ac,</span> <span>dictum</span> <span>sed</span> <span>nulla.</span> <span>Etiam</span> <span>porttitor</span> <span>orci</span> <span>a</span> <span>nibh</span> <span>pharetra,</span> <span>non</span>          <span>pellentesque</span> <span>velit</span> <span>venenatis.</span> <span>Integer</span> <span>a</span> <span>sapien</span> <span>vitae</span> <span>tellus</span> <span>varius</span> <span>rutrum.</span> <span>Mauris</span> <span>ornare</span>          <span>nisi</span> <span>leo,</span> <span>et</span> <span>varius</span> <span>neque</span> <span>scelerisque</span> <span>nec.</span> <span>Nulla</span> <span>venenatis</span> <span>velit</span> <span>at</span> <span>mollis</span> <span>tempor.</span>          <span>Phasellus</span> <span>ex.</span></p>
      </div>
      <div id="generated">Generated 12 paragraphs, 1000 words, 6815 bytes of <a href="https://www.lipsum.com/" title="Lorem Ipsum">Lorem Ipsum</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>



</div>
```